# Code Coverage with Visual Studio Test task

Tags: azure-devops, code-coverage, visual-studio-test-runner

I have a project containing azure function implementations. My project .csproj file looks like below.
[image]

I haved added a test project for the same and implemented unit tests using Xunit. My test project .csproj looks like below.

[image]

I have added a Visual Studio Test task in my build definition with below configurations.

[image]

How can I include only project and test project for calculating code coverage?

Comment: What's the mean for "`include only project and test project for calculating code coverage`"? Generally it can only filter the test assemblies, that means only the test project...

Comment: I meant to calculate code coverage only for the project under test and the test project and I want to exclude all other DLLs from code coverage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Run settings file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file?view=vs-2017) which is the configuration file used by unit testing tools. Advanced code coverage settings are specified in a `.runsettings` file.

You can exclude specified assemblies from code coverage analysis.  For example:

```
<ModulePaths>
  <Exclude>
   <ModulePath>Fabrikam.Math.UnitTest.dll</ModulePath>
   <!-- Add more ModulePath nodes here. -->
  </Exclude>
</ModulePaths>
```

Then add the `.runsettings` file in source control, specify the file under `Setting file` area in Visual Studio Test task

Please see [Customize code coverage analysis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/customizing-code-coverage-analysis?view=vs-2017) for details.